# d3js why are my fixed nodes moving?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, fixed, force-layout

My problem is the following : although I set `fixed : true` for my nodes, only the first one (loaded from the json file) is fixed. The new ones (created by the user) are not fixed, even if with the developer tool of the browser, we can see the `fixed="true"` attribute. Is something missing in the `redraw()` function ? Should I use the `tick()` one ? I'm fighting on this problem for a week and I have no idea anymore.

Here is my entire code (where the initial node is really fixed), but I also propose a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8nfq9y5e/) (where the initial node isn't fixed, too).

```
// Plan
var width = 960,
    height = 500;

// Orange selected element
var selected_node = null,
    selected_link = null;

// Element we clicked on it
var mouseclick_node = null,
    mouseclick_link = null;

// To detect click or double click.
var clickedOnce = false,
    timer;

// Useful function to compute the size of an element.
d3.selection.prototype.size = function() {
  var n = 0;
  this.each(function() { ++n; });
  return n;
};


var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("pointer-events", "all");

var visual = svg
   .append('svg:g')
   .append('svg:g')
      .on("mousemove", mousemove)
      .on("click", click);

// ajoute une balise rect nested dans g, ave préfix svg
visual.append('svg:rect')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height)
    .attr('fill', 'white');

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .size([width, height])
    .charge(-400)
    .on("tick", tick);

// Future link
var drag_line = visual.append("line")
    .attr("class", "drag_line")
    .attr("x1", 0)
    .attr("y1", 0)
    .attr("x2", 0)
    .attr("y2", 0);

// get layout properties
var nodes = force.nodes(),
    links = force.links();
var node = visual.selectAll(".node"),
    link = visual.selectAll(".link");

// Allows the drag actions 
var drag = force.drag();

// Read the json file and creates the links and the nodes
  d3.json("graph_empty.json", function(error, graph) {

    if (error) console.log("error: " + error);   

    nodes = graph.nodes;
    links = graph.links;

    // To redraw after loading nodes and links
    redraw();
});


// Add properties to links and nodes
function tick() {
    link.attr("x1", function (d) {
        return d.source.x;
    })
        .attr("y1", function (d) {
        return d.source.y;
    })
        .attr("x2", function (d) {
        return d.target.x;
    })
        .attr("y2", function (d) {
        return d.target.y;
    });

    node.attr("cx", function (d) {
        return d.x;
    })
        .attr("cy", function (d) {
        return d.y;
    });
}


function mousemove() {
  var point = d3.mouse(this), p = {x: point[0], y: point[1]};

  if (selected_node) {
    drag_line
      .attr("x1", selected_node.x)
      .attr("y1", selected_node.y)
      .attr("x2", p.x)
      .attr("y2", p.y);
  }
}

function click() { 
  var point = d3.mouse(this), p = {x: point[0], y: point[1]};

  // if already clicked once
  if (clickedOnce) {
      run_on_double_click();
  }
  // otherwise
  else {
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
       run_on_simple_click(point);
    }, 150);
    clickedOnce = true;
  }
}

function run_on_simple_click(p) {
  console.log("[run_on_simple_click]");
  clickedOnce = false;

  if (!mouseclick_node && selected_node) {

    // add a new node
    point = {x: p[0], y: p[1]};   
    nodes.push(point);

    // add link to mousedown node
    links.push({source: selected_node, target: point});

    // select the new node
    selected_node = point;
    selected_link = null;

    // update the drag line
    drag_line
      .attr("x1", selected_node.x)
      .attr("y1", selected_node.y)
      .attr("x2", p.x)
      .attr("y2", p.y);

    redraw();
  } 
}

function run_on_double_click() {
    clickedOnce = false;
    clearTimeout(timer);
    console.log("[run_on_double_click]");
}

function resetMouseVars() {
  console.log("[resetMouseVars]");
  mouseclick_node = null;
  mouseclick_link = null;
}

function redraw() {
  console.log("[redraw start]");

  force
      .nodes(nodes)
      .links(links)

  link = link.data(links);

  link.enter().append("line")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .on("click", function(d) {
        // double click:
        if (clickedOnce_On) {
            clickedOnce_On = false;
            clearTimeout(timer);

            mouseclick_link = d;
            if (!selected_link)
              selected_link = mouseclick_link;
            else if (mouseclick_link == selected_link) 
              selected_link = null;
            else if (mouseclick_link == selected_link) {
              selected_link = null; 
              selected_link = mouseclick_link;
            } 
            selected_node = null; 
            resetMouseVars();
            redraw(); 
        }
        // single click:
        else {
          timer = setTimeout(function() {
             // to do... create a new node between !
          }, 250);
          clickedOnce_On = true;
        }
    });

  link.exit().remove();

  link.classed("link_selected", function(d) { 
                  return d === selected_link; 
              });

  node = node.data(nodes);

  var clickedOnce_On = false;
  node.enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("r", 6)
    .attr("fixed", true)
    .call(drag)
    .on("click", function(d) {
        mouseclick_node = d;

        // double click:
        if (clickedOnce_On) {
            clickedOnce_On = false;
            clearTimeout(timer);

            if (!selected_node)
                selected_node = mouseclick_node;
            else if (mouseclick_node == selected_node) 
              selected_node = null;
            else if (mouseclick_node == selected_node) {
              selected_node = null; 
              selected_node = mouseclick_node;
            } 
            selected_link = null; 
            resetMouseVars();
            redraw(); 
        }
        // single click:
        else {
          timer = setTimeout(function() {
            // close the surface if
             if ((selected_node) && (mouseclick_node) && (selected_node !=  mouseclick_node)) {
                console.log("mouseclick_node: "+ mouseclick_node);
                // Here: count the number of links for each node
                // and find the node with only one link.
                // If this node == mouseclick_node,
                // we add a new link between it and the selected_node.
                resetMouseVars();
                redraw(); 
             }
          }, 250);
          clickedOnce_On = true;
        }
    });

  node.exit().transition()
    .attr("r", 0)
    .remove();

  node.classed("node_selected", function(d) { 
                  return d === selected_node; 
              }); 
  force
      .start()
      .tick();

  console.log("[redraw end]");
}
```

Thank you very much in advance, for any suggestions/comments/solutions !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution: I set the attributes of the `force` like this:

```
var force = d3.layout.force()
    .size([width, height])
    .charge(0)
    .gravity(0)
    .linkStrength(0)
    .friction(0)
    .on("tick", tick);
```

In this way, all my fixed nodes do not move, except when I drag them.